# Creating an instance using a manager method in a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a very simple `ModelForm` for creating a new user (almost entirely based on the stock `UserCreationForm`. My `User` model has its own manager, which has a `create_user` method that creates a new instance, sets the password, opt out from newsletters, and performs other house keeping.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None, email=None, save=True):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, password
        and email
        """
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        user.notificationoptout_set.create(notification_type=const.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NEWSLETTER)

        if save:
            user.save()

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   # ...
   objects = UserManager()
```

Is it not good design to have a custom creation method given that the form will be the gateway to user creation anyway? Should all the house keeping be moved to the form, e.g., into the `save` method? Something like:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
#...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(TestUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = user.normalize_email(self.cleaned_data.get("email"))
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.notificationoptout_set.create(notification_type=const.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NEWSLETTER)

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form is not the only way to create users.  `UserManager.create_user()` method is used in the `manage.py createsuperuser` command.